# Noncommutativization of fixed point theory

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, fixed-point-theorems

What papers or references  have been devoted for  a  noncommutativization of "Fixed point theory". Here the terminology Noncommutativiztion, as usual, indicates to that famous table with 2  columns: first column is the classic(space) and the second is "operator algebra". See for example table in page 26 [of Connes book](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf)  or  page 6 of [this  note](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408416v1.pdf)

For $A=C(X)$ the  algebraic translation is that "For every  unital morphism $\phi$ on $A$, there is  a maximal ideal $I$ which is invariant under $\phi$.  Now what is  an appropriate NC analogy?

In this line, is  it reasonable to search  for  a particular  type of $\textit{index}$ as  a  NC  analogue for  Lefschetz index?

Comment: Is $\phi$ an automorphism or any endomorphism? Under $\phi$ or under $\phi^{-1}$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  a unital endomorphism. by invariant I mean $\phi(I)\subset I$.(an algebraic translation of the classical fix point property, according to Gelfand duality.

Comment: I see. Though in fact for a maximal $I$ it is equivalent to $\phi^{-1}(I)=I$...